# OpenGL frame buffer + LibGDX

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, libgdx, framebuffer

I have one problem with openGL frame buffer.
I want to achieve:

1. Bind FBO1. Draw image1 to FBO1. Unbind FBO1.
2. Bind FBO2. Draw FBO1 to FBO2. Unbind FBO2.
3. Bind FBO1. Draw image2 to FBO1. Unbind FBO1.
4. Draw FBO2 to the screen

What I expect to see:
I expect to see only image1 on the screen, because it is drawn in the first FBO and then the first FBO is drawn onto the second FBO

What is the problem:
I am seeing both image1 and image2 on drawn, which should be imposible, because only the first image is drawn in FBO1 when FBO1 is drawn in FBO2 and I only draw FBO2 to the screen.

Here is the code to reproduce the problem:

```
// --- in show() method
this.img = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("shaders/image.jpg"));
this.img2 = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("shaders/image2.jpg"));
this.fbo = new FrameBuffer(Format.RGBA8888, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), false);
this.fbo2 = new FrameBuffer(Format.RGBA8888, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), false);

// --- in render() method
// start frame buffer 1 and draw image 1
this.fbo.begin();
{
    this.batch.begin();
    this.batch.draw(this.img, 0, 0, 400, 400, 0, 0, this.img.getWidth(), this.img.getHeight(), false, true);
    this.batch.end();
}
this.fbo.end();

// start frame buffer 2 and frame buffer 1 output
this.fbo2.begin();
{
    this.batch.begin();
    this.batch.draw(this.fbo.getColorBufferTexture(), 500, 0, this.fbo.getColorBufferTexture().getWidth(), this.fbo.getColorBufferTexture().getHeight(), 0, 0, this.fbo.getColorBufferTexture()
            .getWidth(), this.fbo.getColorBufferTexture().getHeight(), false, true);
    this.batch.end();
}
this.fbo2.end();

// start frame buffer 1 again and draw image 2
this.fbo.begin();
{
    this.batch.begin();
    this.batch.draw(this.img2, 150, 150, 400, 400, 0, 0, this.img2.getWidth(), this.img2.getHeight(), false, true);
    this.batch.end();
}
this.fbo.end();

// draw frame buffer 2 to the batch
this.batch.begin();
this.batch.draw(this.fbo2.getColorBufferTexture(), 0, 0);
this.batch.end();
```

The draw() methods are a bit long, because I want to pass flipY = true, because OpenGL draws the frame buffers upside-down.

The parameters of the draw() method that I am using are:

```
Texture texture, float x, float y, float width, float height, int srcX, int srcY, int srcWidth, int srcHeight, boolean flipX, boolean flipY
```

What am I missing? Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you begin drawing on another FrameBuffer, you need to clear it if you don't want the old contents.

```
frameBuffer.begin();
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
//...
```

You also need to clear the screen at the beginning of `render()` if you don't want the contents from the last call to `render()`.

Also, if you are covering the whole background with your image, you might as well disable blending on the SpriteBatch.

Comment: Actually I called glClear but I did it before I bind the buffer and somehow I didn't notice it. But now after seeing your comment I reviewed my code again and this time I saw it. Thank you!